# Raw não renderiza link em vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Estou fazendo um trecho de código que  retorna também uma string no vb.net mvc 4.5  no entanto a string é montada corretamente.

Mas na view

```
@Html.Raw(item.metodo.ToString())
```

ele não esa apresentando os links

a string estou  montando assim

```
strDiv += "<a href='#' id='" + reader("Nome").ToString().Trim + "' onclick='mostrar_abas(this);'>" + reader("Nome").ToString().Trim + "</a>"

strDiv += "<div id='div_" + reader("Lista").ToString().Trim + "'>   ABCDE</div>"
```

e passo esa string para o connstrutor mas na hora de exibir ele exibe a Div o conteudo da div mas não exibe os links

Comment: Desculpe eu me perdi aqui no site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema na verdade é que  no caso a fonte do link estava na mesma cor do fundo da página a rotina estava funcionando perfeitamente